# Архитектура приложения C# Command Server + Android Client, как лучше сделать?

Tags: c#, android, архитектура, sql-server, клиент-сервер

Итак, сабж:

Напрягаю мозги, как организовать систему мониторинга за устройствами на компьютерах сети. Мне нужно знать, в каком состоянии устройство на конкретном компьютере и его последние действия. И это "нужно знать" должно быть реализовано в виде андроид-приложения, которое эти состояния будет отображать.

Есть N компьютеров, на каждом в трее висит бот, мониторящий процессы, связанные с устройством и пишет лог в удаленную MS SQL базу (реализовано) и , возможно, в последствии нужно будет, чтобы этот бот получал команды и выполнял их (например, замочить какой-то процесс или перезапустить). Я подумал, что raw-SQL запросы с каждого компьютера - это как-то несерьезно и, выяснив после прочтения хабра , что напрямую из андроида к MS SQL не законнектиться, решил объединить все операции, связанные с базой, в Command Server. Через него , думается, все операции с базой и будут проходить. Посредством сокетов я вроде разобрался как принимать и отправлять сообщения, типа "HelloWorld". Но тут встало сразу много вопросов:

- Слишком много звеньев в цепи, может как-то сократить можно?

Вход: MonitoringBot -> CommandServer -> MS SQL Insert, Update commands

Выход: AndroidClient -> CommandServer -> MS SQL Select command

Управление: AndroidClient -> CommandServer -> MonitoringBot win Commands -> CommandServer -> Response to AndroidClient

- В каком виде лучше всего слать команды? Может протокол какой-то нужно использовать?
- Как оперативно обновлять инфу на AndroidClient при изменениях в базе?
- Есть ли другие варианты реализации этой задачи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP Webservice? Android client -> send webserivce command, Android client -> ping some time for db status by ASP Webservice?

На мой взгляд замкнуть взаимодействие через CommandServer - хорошая идея. Пропишите просто грамотное апи.

Comment: А по командам ничего не подскажите? Может протокол какой лучше заюзать? А то парсить строки вручную как-то не комильфо...

Comment: А зачем Вам что то парсить в ручную используя веб сервис?

Comment: Парсить - это я имел ввиду если просто CommandServer, без ASP WebService.

Comment: XML? JSON?

Comment: попробую последовать вашему совету и избежать CommandServer и сокеты, и изучить ASP.NET WebServices.

Comment: хотя все же остается непонятно как подключенным клиентам(android) оперативно рассылать какие-нибудь сообщения. К Web-службе, как я понимаю, только обращение (с запросом) идет, клиентам она самостоятельно (без запроса) не может же рассылать ничего?

Comment: Да, верно. Но я не совсем понимаю зачем Вам такая оперативность? Опрос веб сервиса с определённой частотой думаю решит эту проблему?
В крайнем случае можете оставить сокет как раз только для цели чтобы сказать клиенту - ткнись на веб сервис. Но где гарантия что сокет не отвалится например после того как пропала сеть не на долго?

Comment: Для двунаправленного общения между клиентами и сервером можно использовать http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html